# RAILS precision and scale of decimal is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have set :precision => 8, :scale => 2 in decimal of migration but when i input 1923.423453 it is still  1923.4 . It should be 1923.42 ... right?

```
t.decimal :value , :precision => 8, :scale => 2 , :default => 0
```

Comment: How is this column defined in your database? Does it match your settings from the migration?

Comment: yap , migration same with the console

Comment: I just double-checked and compared with some of my own migrations, and your code looks fine. No idea why it's not working. What happens if you call object.value.to_f, does it really round off to a single decimal? Have you checked what the value in the database is directly, through the mysql commandline or HeidiSQL or something?

Comment: Item.first.value.to_f => 12123.123123 . SQLITE show the same ... wonder why ...

Comment: I think gonna do this in model level ....

Comment: Are you following Agile Web Development with Rails? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: yap , i'm following agile web development .... i'm using ubuntu with rails 3 ... you?

Comment: mac os. rails 3. i don't see where we're going wrong. this is the sqlite3 schema: 'CREATE TABLE "products" (.. "price" decimal(8,2) ..);' that seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: i get that also. But i overwrite the price method def price end def price=(pc) end with round method inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently all sqlite options are dropped on migration.

Here's the lighthouse ticket targeting milestone 3.0.4 to fix this issue:
https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2872-patch-sqlite3-adapter-drops-decimal-columns-precision-scale-when-migration-tries-to-alter-them

Comment: so what i need to do it upgrade my rails sqlite adapter ?

Comment: I haven't tried the patch myself, but looking at the changes targeted to be included in the 3.0.4 milestone, you'd have to update the sqlite_adapter.rb file as detailed in this gist(it's the content of the patch in the lighthouse ticket above): https://gist.github.com/724939

Comment: Yepp, it have been merged to master w/ this PR:
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3400
and included in Rails since version 3.2.0